# Not able to use AgmMarkerSpiderModule

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I try to add AgmMarkerSpiderModule as described https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-spiderfier. But i get this message on compile;

```
/directives/marker-spider.ts:14:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@agm/markerclusterer": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/router": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^10.1.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@google/markerclustererplus": "^5.1.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.12",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "agm-spiderfier": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "ts-overlapping-marker-spiderfier": "^1.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
```

anyone able to help me out here?

Comment: did you also import AgmCoreModule to the module like the link you provided describe? did you run npm install?

Comment: Yes. Still get the error-message. The click-event works though.

Comment: running tests i get "ERROR in The target entry-point "agm-spiderfier" has missing dependencies:
 - @agm/core/services/google-maps-types"

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work:

make sure to use below versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.2",
    "agm-spiderfier": "1.0.1",
}
```

Please try below steps:

1. delete node_modules folder.
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install`

HTML Template :

```
<agm-map class="agm-map" [zoom]="zoom" [zoomControl]="true" [disableDefaultUI]="false" [streetViewControl]="false"
    (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)" [fitBounds]="true">
    <agm-marker-spider>
        <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index" [latitude]="m.lat" [longitude]="m.lng" [label]="m.label"
            [agmFitBounds]="true">

            <agm-snazzy-info-window [closeWhenOthersOpen]="true" [disableAutoPan]="false">
                <ng-template>
                    <h3 class="marker-title">
                        Window Title
                    </h3>
                    <div class="">
                        Info Window Content
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </agm-snazzy-info-window>

        </agm-marker>
    </agm-marker-spider>
</agm-map>
```

Component.ts:

```
zoom: number = 6;
map: any;
lat: number = null;
lng: number = null;

public onMapReady(map) {
  this.map = map;
}
markers = [
  {
    lat: 51.673858,
    lng: 7.815982,
    label: "A",
    draggable: true
  },
  {
    lat: 51.373858,
    lng: 7.215982,
    label: "B",
    draggable: false
  },
  {
    lat: 51.723858,
    lng: 7.895982,
    label: "C",
    draggable: true,
  },
  {
    lat: 17.385,
    lng: 78.4867,
    label: "D",
    draggable: true,
  }
];
```